# Drools: Accessing ArrayList as value in Map

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, drools

I am trying to access the elements of the ArrayList that is the value of a map.

For example:

{"height": [-10,20]} and I am trying to get the individual value say "-10" in order to make a comparison in the when condition.

Right now i am doing:

```
rule "test"
when
    Params(tol: tolerance)    //recieving the Map
    eval( tol.get("height").get(0) < 0 ) 
then
   ...
end
```

It says that the get function is not part of the type Object. How do i get to the arraylist value?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your classes look something like this:

```
class Params {
  private Map<String, List<Integer>> tolerance;
  public Map<String, List<Integer>> getTolerance() { return this.tolerance; }
}
```

Then you should be able to structure a rule like this:

```
rule "test"
when
  // get the Tolerance map and assign to $tolerance
  Params( $tolerance: tolerance ) 

  // get the 'height' list from the $tolerance map, assign to $height
  Map( $height: this["height"] ) from $tolerance

  // Check if the first integer in the $height list is negative
  Integer( this < 0 ) from $height.get(0)
then
   ...
end
```

The `this[ key ]` syntax only works for Maps. Depending on how you've configured Drools and how old the version of Drools you're using is, `$height` may be extracted as an object, which means you'll have to first convert to list before you use the `get(#)` method.

Avoid `eval` whenever possible because the Drools compiler cannot optimize those calls.

Comment: does that mean just having a List() line in-between the Map and Integer one?

Comment: Something like `$heightList: ArrayList() from $height` would be sufficient to cast. Maps should be avoided in general as rule inputs ... this is very much something that was popular in Drools 4 and was already discouraged by Drools 5.